# R: coding barcharts with gradient color in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, visualization, gradient

Our data are depth intervals (subsea) in several locations, which have some property ("anomaly coefficients" with values around 1). These coefficients are in general different for the top and the bottom of our intervals, in the minimal example these are `coef1` and `coef2` fields. We visualize these depth intervals in `ggplot2` with barcharts at appropriate depths and color code them according to the value of these coefficients. The data to be read in R:

```
dat.gr<-read.csv(text="field,coef1,coef2,d1,d2
location 1,0.96,1.02,1938,1528
location 2,0.44,0.92,564,923
location 3,0.66,1.39,2522,1300
location 4,1.127,1.41,2900,1030")
```

The barchart with color coding by one value of this coefficient (coef1) looks as follows:

[image: bar chart color coded with a value]

and is produced by the code (arranged slightly beyond the "minimal example" in order to show columns in their natural positions downwards from the sea level):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat.gr.tidied<-dat.gr %>% 
gather(key=pos,value=depth,-field,-coef1,-coef2)

ggplot(dat.gr.tidied,aes(x=field,y=depth,alpha=pos,fill=coef1))+
geom_col(position=position_stack(reverse=T))+
scale_y_continuous(trans="reverse")+
scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.05, 1))
```

How to code each bar in a chart with a *color gradient* from the value coef1 on its top to coef2 on the bottom? Second question is: how to control the color map of these codings, choosing another coloring, for example, as it is used for heatmaps with color range green (<1) - yellow (coef=1) -red (>1) ? (in heat maps it is done by the directive like `col_fun=colorRamp2(c(-2, 0, 2), c("green", "yellow", "red"))`

Comment: I don't think ggplot2 has built in functionality to fill individual columns with gradients, you will need either a workaround or a different graphics program/package.  As far as the green/yellow/red scale you are looking for, check out the the "RdYlGn" diverging scale in the RColorBrewer package.